# How to pass dynamic segment to ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do I pass a dynamic segment in my url to a component? I can get the parameters in my model but i have no idea, how to pass that on to the component. What I do right now is:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    sectionId: 0,

    model(params) {
        this.set('sectionId', params.section_id);
        return this.store.findAll('content');
    }
});
```

And in the Template:

```
{{#component id=sectionId}}{{/component}}
```

But when I log the id in my component, it says undefined.

Comment: `sectionId` in the template will not find a property on the route.

Comment: Ember.set(this.get('controller'), 'sectionId', params.section_id). However i dont understand the point of using segmented route and not having anything on queried on your model. Maybe you could post more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set controller properties in `setupController` hook.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    sectionId: 0,

    model(params) {
        this.set('sectionId', params.section_id);
        return this.store.findAll('content');
    },

     setupController(controller, model) {
       controller.set('sectionId', this.get('sectionId'));
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your controller can have access to the params](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/query-params/), so make sure you declare that in your controller.

For example, for your controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['section'],
  section: null
});
```

And in your template:

```
{{#component id=section}}{{/component}}
```

Note that this is assuming your url looks something like `http://example.com/posts/1?section=3`